# What is the best way to handle more bone weights than allowed in code?

Tags: directx11, skeletal-animation, assimp

I am currently attempting to incorporate animated models in my game engine, using Assimp to load the models. I can load and render the static model just fine, but when I try to enable the animation, it basically explodes. I can tell the animation is there and running smoothly, though something isn't working properly.

I have many things to explore in solving the issues at hand, but one in particular is troubling: The code is written to handle 4 bone weights, mostly because it appears to be fairly standard and is easy to pass to the shader. But the model has more than 4 weights per vertex.

So my question is this: What is the best way to handle having more bone weights than the code/shader can handle? Should I run through all the weights and pick the top 4 and adjust them to add up to 1? I could probably code for more weights, but then where does it end?

Comment: It sounds like you have a plausible plan in mind. What happens when you put that idea into practice?

Comment: *"run through all the weights and pick the top 4 and adjust them to add up to 1"* - sounds like a good plan. I have working animations with just 2 weights per vertex - even this performs very good.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually went with an "all of the above" solution to this, and it works perfectly. I went with keeping the top 8 weights and normalize them to 1. This was a good idea anyway, because I found that the weights aren't normalized to 1 in many models.